# Tab selection in URL (Shiny - Shiny Dashboard)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny app with the following structure:

```
shinyUI(dashboardPage(title="Map",
                      dashboardHeader(title = tags$img(src="logo.png")),
                      dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "totalTab",
                                       menuItem("Users", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("user-circle")),
                                       menuItem("Map", tabName = "cities", icon = icon("map-o")),
                                       menuItem("Med", tabName = "med", icon = icon("building-o"), selected = TRUE),                                   
                                       menuItem("Data", tabName = "opdata", icon = icon("database"))
                                       ),
                      dashboardBody(tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", uiOutput("bodyuser")),
                        tabItem(tabName = "med", uiOutput("bodyoutput")),
                        tabItem(tabName = "cities", uiOutput("citiesout")),
                        tabItem(tabName = "opdata", uiOutput("dataout"))
                      ))
))
```

The first I see when I open the app is tab item "med". Inside "med" I have a tabset called "TabMap". I want to update "TabMap" using URL like this:

```
observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if (!is.null(query[['panelname']])) {
      rv$rvpanel <- query[['panelname']]
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "TabMap", selected = rv$rvpanel)
    }
  })
```

Or this:

```
observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if (!is.null(query[['panelname']])) {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "TabMap", selected = query[['panelname']])
    }
  })
```

But neither works. How can I do that?

PD: rv$rvpanel is a reactive value...

Tabset:

```
  output$bodyoutput <- renderUI({
    box(title = "Map", width ="100%", status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
        uiOutput("tabmap"))
  })

  output$tabmap <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(id = "TabMap",
                tabPanel(width = "100%", title = "Add", value="panel5", uiOutput("formdead")),
                tabPanel(width = "100%", title = "Ours", value="panel1", uiOutput("mapdeadout")),
                tabPanel(width = "100%", title = "Month", value="panel4", uiOutput("mapmonthout")),
                tabPanel(width = "100%", title = "Map", value = "panel2", uiOutput("maplifeout")),
                tabPanel(width = "100%", title = "History", value="panel3", uiOutput("formhist"))
                )
  })
```

Comment: i dont see your tabsetpanel,...?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Edited

Answer (score 0):

You just missed one thing, to check if `"TabMap"` is already rendered and available in the input before your observe code gets executed.

This codes below seem to work

```
 observe({
        if(any(names(input) == "TabMap")){
          query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
          if (!is.null(query[['panelname']])) {
            rv$rvpanel <- query[['panelname']]
            updateTabsetPanel(session, "TabMap", selected = rv$rvpanel)

          } 
        }

      })




  observe({
        if(any(names(input) == "TabMap")){
          query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
          if (!is.null(query[['panelname']])) {
            updateTabsetPanel(session, "TabMap", selected = query[['panelname']])
          } 
        }

      })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! But I need to create it before, it has to be shown. I had to avoid uiOutput in the first "TabMap"